# GmailDraft.send() changes the Message ID : how to override this?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

The message ID changes when I send a draft, as in the code below.

```
// make draft
var draft = GmailApp.createDraft("test@gmail.com", "Email Subject", "Email Body");
var draftId = draft.getMessage().getId();

// send draft
var message = draft.send();
var messageId = message.getId();

// this returns 'false'
Logger.log(draftId == messageId);
```

Is there a way to override this (keep the same message ID) in two scenarios :

- Scenario 1: when sending an email programmatically as above?
- Scanerio 2: when sending the draft (generated with code as above) manually by clicking "send" on my gmail page?

The point is to be able to find an email generated in my code (and sent immediately or later, manually) in another function. I thought Message ID would be a good tracker ; but if the above seems too difficult, is there a better way of finding a specific email generated in code later on?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The message id changes because it is now a sent message and not a draft. You could benefit from a review of the underlying Gmail API and the details of MIME messages.

Comment: To correlate a sent message id with the source draft id, use your preferred associative container, e.g. `sent[<some key from the draft>].push(message.getId())` (after of course initializing the relevant key to an array in preceding code)

Comment: Thanks for giving me the pointers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple workaround: using the Thread ID: `var threadId = message.getThread().getId();`

The Thread ID of a given draft and the Thread ID of the message generated once that draft is sent are exactly the same. So this is the "good tracker" I was looking for.

Of course this does not answer the post's original question directly, but it allows me to do everything I wanted to do (finding a specific email generated in code later on).